# Changing column values?

Tags: r

I have a table with 5 columns. 3rd column contains numbers from 1-5. I want to replace numbers with letters where 1=A, 2=D, 3=X and 4=U and 5=K. How can I do so in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a lookup table, i.e. a `list` where the names are the numbers 1-5, and the content of the list the letters A-E:

```
lut = list('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
names(lut) = 1:5
sample_data = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
as.character(lut[as.character(sample_data)])

> lut
$`1`
[1] "A"

$`2`
[1] "B"

$`3`
[1] "C"

$`4`
[1] "D"

$`5`
[1] "E"

> sample_data
 [1] 3 5 2 5 1 4 2 2 3 3
> as.character(lut[as.character(sample_data)])
 [1] "C" "E" "B" "E" "A" "D" "B" "B" "C" "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be easier to understand than Paul's answer (which is a better approach IMHO).

Create a little dataframe, which is essentially a lookup table.  Then, where I let `bar` be the column of interest in your array,

```
Rgames> foo
$lets
[1] "A" "D" "X" "U" "K"

$nums
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

Rgames> rab<-foo$lets[bar]
Rgames> rab
[1] "A" "A" "X" "D" "K"
Rgames> foo
$lets
[1] "A" "D" "X" "U" "K"

$nums
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

Rgames> bar
[1] 1 1 3 2 5
Rgames> foo$lets[bar]
[1] "A" "A" "X" "D" "K"
```

replace the column values with the output of that last line, and you're all set.